# Is the set $M := \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| + \operatorname{Re}(z) \leq 1\}$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I want to investigate whether the set $M$ mentioned in the question is compact. I know that $M$ has to be closed and bounded in order to be compact.

$M$ is not bounded since for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{-}$ we have that $|z| + \operatorname{Re}(z) = x -x = 0 \leq 1$. Therefore $x \in M$. So we know that $M$ can't be compact. Still I am curious how I can investigate whether the set is closed or not. How can this be done here?

Comment: $z\mapsto |z|+$Re$(z)$ is a continuous (over $\mathbb{R})$ function and $M$ is the inverse image of the interval $[-1,1]$. Hence $M$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it isn't bounded, you have your answer, regardless of closedness. That being said, the function $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb R$ given by
$$
f(z)=|z|+\operatorname{Re}(z)
$$
is continuous, and your $M$ is the inverse image of a closed set under this function.